# In Java, does a check of a collection for emptiness before applying a stream functoin chain on it improve performance?

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

how does the Stream API perform on empty collections? Does it make sense to check for emptiness before executing a stream command chain on a collection?

For example, is the total runtime better for the first or the second example block?

```
List a = new ArrayList(); 
return a.stream.anyMatch("OK"::equals).orElse(null);
```

vs

```
List a = new ArrayList();
if(a.isEmpty()) {
    return null;
} else {
    return a.stream.anyMatch("OK"::equals).orElse(null);
}
```

I am aware of that the first option is more *beautiful*, but this is a question about performance.

Comment: from a simplicity purpose, no it doesn't make much sense as the stream itself doesn't perform any operation when the collection is empty.

Comment: Smells like premature optimization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it make sense to check for emptiness before executing a stream command chain on a collection?

It might make from a performance point of view, as it definitely prevents an empty stream spending (a bit) of CPU time doing nothing.

But from a conceptual point of view: not a good idea. The whole point of streams is that you do not *care* about the number of entries. Streams are (to a large degree) a way to express logic in "functional programming" ways. An empty stream comes back with an "empty" result. That is how they work and should be used.

If you add a distinct check upfront, then your code will also need to provide that empty result for example.

Regarding performance, the thing that you *really* want to be cautious about: having a *lot* of stream operations that run *very often* on small numbers of elements.

Comment: “*prevents an empty stream spending (a bit) of CPU time doing nothing*”. It never does nothing. It performs an operation that will end up detecting (perhaps implicitly) that the collection is empty. So you spend time checking for an empty collection to prevent the Stream from detecting an empty collection. There might be differences in the amount of CPU time needed to do the same thing then, but if you care about such tiny amounts of CPU time, it should not be forgotten that the extra check also has to be paid when the collection is *not* empty.